# Powerpoint 2010 - Play both videos on click and reset videos on click

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How do I play both videos ON CLICK ? I do not want it to be played automatically. Also, how do i reset both videos on click ?

Means like I got 2 videos but control both with one button. Help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open the PowerPoint presentation. From the tab menu go to *Insert
  -> Video -> Insert Video from file...* as in the picture below

[How to insert a video - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppJVc.png)

- Repeat the step to add your second video.
- Select the two videos and a new tab will appear called "Video Tools". Go to *Video Tools -> Playback* and at the *Start* option select *Automatically* as highlighted in the picture below.

[Automatically start video - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZsN4.png)

- Go to *Animations -> Animation Tab* and in the "Animation Tab" that will appear right click on the first video and select "Start after previous", then right click on the second video and select "Start with previous".
- Make sure that the two videos are selected and go to Animations -> Add animation and select "Appear" (or any other animation you wish).
- From the "Animation Panel" move the two "Appear" animations to the top of the list. Right click the first one and select "Start on click" and for the second "Appear" animation select "Start with previous.